# Responsive design best practice: Duplicate html elements for media querying and SEO impact?

Tags: css, html, seo, responsive-design, media-queries

EDIT : Question closed, see webmasters.stackexchange:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43038/responsive-design-best-practice-duplicate-html-elements-for-media-querying-and/43100#43100

I have a page with, in order of html appearance, a `figure` tag, `headgroup` tag, and an `article` tag.

In order to make a page's design responsive using media queries, I need a different order for elements, so the image appears after the title.

The simplest solution I can think of is cloning the `headgroup` tag in the source code and place the copy before the `figure` tag, thus making it possible to show/hide the appropriate tag according to viewport size.

But I have the feeling this is not ideal SEO-wise.

My question is simple:

Does this simple technique really have an impact on SEO?

Is there an html attribute to declare duplicate elements in a page?

Is there another recommended solution? Best practice?

Thanks in advance for any advised input!